# Accessing the DOM tree from an Electron child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, ipc, electron

I'm using Electron (v1.2.2) on Windows 10 and I have a big problem with one of my projects :

I have a script with turns into the renderer process and create child processes to run some special code. I need the code runned inside the child process to access the DOM.
When the process is created (with child_process.fork()) I send some informations using the built-in IPC channel such as the timestamp, some informations about the script which will run inside the child process...

But when I try to send an instance of a class it doesn't work at all :

```
//main.js
const child_process = require('child_process');
const child = child_process.fork('child.js');
child.send({ready: { version: '0.0.1', dom: document }});

// child.js
process.on('message', (m) => {
    typeof m.dom.body.appendChild; // ReferenceError
});
```

I suppose that is a limitation of IPC communication that can only transmit some specific datas, but I know it's possible to send a server or a socket instance using an IPC channel, so I don't understand why it's not possible to transmit a Document.

So I was looking for a way to access the DOM from the child process but I didn't found any solution.
The code inside the child process needs to do a lot of operations on the DOM and can't use IPC communication to access it, else the performances will be too slow.

So, my question is : Is there any way to access the DOM from a child process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion into the [Electron](https://github.com/Electron/electron) issues page, it appears that this problem is not solvable ; there is no way to access the DOM into a child process because Electron (like nw.js) is not designed for that.

More informations at : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7057

**EDIT :** Finally I found another way to solve my problem by using the `webview` tag which permit to run an HTML page with Node.js features and always into a new process. More informations [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7057#issuecomment-244435830)